# Spring security jsf login page not invoked

Tags: jsf, spring-security

My Problem is when want to request some pages, the `login.xhtml` is not opened to authenticate the user.

Here is the `security-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/faces/login2.xhtml" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/faces/MyCard.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/faces/login2.xhtml" default-target-url="/Home.xhtml"
                             authentication-failure-url="/faces/login2.xhtml?error=1" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="sajjad" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="ssss"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

And this is `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- SPRING SECURITY RELATED CONFIG-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this is the `login bean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

private String username;
private String password;

public String login() throws IOException, ServletException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + username
                    + "&j_password=" + password);

    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse());
    context.responseComplete();
    return null;
}
//getter/setters
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not precising the right login page name in the configuration file. It's `login` not `login2`:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <security:form-login login-page="/faces/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/Home.xhtml"
    ...
</security:http>
```

If it doesn't work, omit `.xhtml`, else keep just `"login"` for login-page attribute.